# In MS Word, how do I un-indent a bullet?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

In MS Word, I have this:

[image]

But what I want is this (below)

[image]

How do I bring my cursor (and current-place-bullet) back to that indentation-bullet-point-level?

Comment: Question very nicely explained, thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will do this.

Comment: Pressing enter before typing anything else will do it on a Mac

Comment: @PMV: pressing Enter before typing anything else reduces indent on a Mac - for an empty paragraph.  What about for a non-empty paragraph?  On Windows, tab/backtab at the start of a paragraph indents/unindents, even if paragraph nonempty.

Answer (score 17):

In addition to the other answers, there are toolbar/ribbon buttons for "Decrease Indent" and "Increase Indent".

[image]

Oh, and one more - I believe if you hit Enter when on a blank item in your list, it decreases its indentation level as well.

Answer (score 10):

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to step back out of the indentation.

Comment: This is not working for me for some reason (MS Word 2007). I can remove the indentation with `Shift+Tab` though.

Answer (score 10):

Ctrl + M / Ctrl + Shift + M controls the indentation level of your bulletted/numbered lists.

Comment: This works when **Shift** + **Tab** and the Increase/Decrease Indent controls do not!

Answer (score 1):

In Google Docs I press Enter twice quickly to 'un-indent' but I don't know if this works for anywhere else... Unfortunately I learnt the very long and hard way.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question which has nothing to do with google docs.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice to get to the previous outline level.

When at the 2nd indent level ("delete P..." in your example), press <kbd>Enter</kbd> once to get to the 1st indent level ("delete M..." in your example). Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice to get up another level to where your arrow points.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Mac OS X, use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>.

Comment: Can you expand upon this? You might want to quote the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Press tab to indent forward. To go back an indent, press tab and then press backspace twice.

Comment: `Shift+Tab` is reverse indent shortcut...

Comment: True, but pressing tab and then backspace does the same thing. It's just another way and it's quicker for me

Comment: 5 year old question.  To repeat what the keyboard combination suggested 5 years ago does.  This answer appeared in the review queue.

Comment: Is that bad? The reason I added an answer is because no one else had mentioned this method of tabbing back

Comment: `ChrisF` suggested it 6 years ago.

Comment: On this thread? I couldn't find where

Comment: [Yes](http://superuser.com/revisions/156382/2) this question.

Comment: That says nothing about pressing tab and then backspacing at least twice